# I keep getting this error in Swift. “Consecutive Declarations On A Line Must Be Separated By ','”

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Whenever I run the code, it says  “Consecutive Declarations On A Line Must Be Separated By ','”

```
var obstacleOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.size.width / 4)
```

Can someone please help me? I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have an extra parenthesis at the end of your statement.

Good Luck!